# Python - Duplicate Tuples in an orderly fashion

Tags: python, duplicates

I would like to find a way to duplicate tuples in my list but in a orderly fashion. Meaning:

Assuming:

```
a = [('c','v','t'),(1,2,3)]
```

and Assuming three duplicates, I am looking for a way to get this:

```
a = [('c','v','t'),('c','v','t'),('c','v','t'),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

So far I use list comprehension

```
[item*3 for item in a]
```

Howver, it breaks the tuples:

```
out = [('c', 'v', 't', 'c', 'v', 't', 'c', 'v', 't'), (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please share us your code

Comment: see above, used a typical list comprehension

Comment: `a = [r for item in a for r in itertools.repeat(item, 3)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
[y for y in a for i in range(3)]
```

Using two loops prevents the issue you have

Comment: You can write `for _ in range(3)` since `i` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) is your friend.

```
import itertools as it


a = [("c", "v", "t"), (1, 2, 3)] 

list(it.chain(*zip(*it.repeat(a, 3))))
# [('c', 'v', 't'), ('c', 'v', 't'), ('c', 'v', 't'), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
dup_num = 3
list1 = [('c', 'v', 't'), (1, 2, 3)]
list2 = [tup2 for tup in list1 for tup2 in [tup] * 3]
```

But I don't really like that.

You can also use a for loop:

```
list2 = []
for tup in list1:
  list2.extend([tup] * 3)
```